# I am using Amazon REDSHIIFT and want to make my table data case insensitive?

Tags: database-recommendation, redshift

How can I change my Tables data stored in REDSHIFT case insensitive?

For example: `Bell`, `BELL`, `bell` in a column should return all the rows when queried.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no way to do that. Redshift doesn't allow you to set specific [collation settings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_collation_sequences.html). To get the CI behavior, you'd have to add either [UPPER()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UPPER.html) or [LOWER()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LOWER.html) consistently to all your queries.

Technically, you could make those case conversions during loading itself and let the application tier handle display data in the appropriate case. However, I'd recommend you do not attempt that unless you know for certain your DW will never have data sets that has to be case sensitive (i.e. source already Y has a different meaning/value from y) or an application that treats different cases differently. In those situations, you've effectively corrupted your data without knowing it.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift now has [collation settings to allow for case insensitivity](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/06/amazon-redshift-now-supports-case-insensitive-collation-with-column-level-overrides/) as of June 24, 2021. One caveat would be that you cannot change the collation settings of a database unless it is empty (as per this [post on their Big Data blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/case-insensitive-collation-support-for-string-processing-in-amazon-redshift/)).

Database creation example:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name [ WITH ]
[ COLLATE CASE_SENSITIVE | COLLATE CASE_INSENSITIVE ]
```

Table creation example:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  col1 Varchar(20) COLLATE case_insensitive
 );
```